# Error "xxxxxxxx takes no arguments", en Python

Tags: python, filtro, lambda

¿Alguien sabe por qué marca error? "Empleado takes no arguments"

```
class Empleado:
    def ___init___(self, nombre, cargo, salario):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.cargo=cargo
        self.salario=salario

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} que trabaja como {} tiene un salario de {} $".format(self.nombre, self.cargo, self.salario)
    
listaEmpleados=[
Empleado("juan", "director", 75000),
Empleado("maria", "presidente", 57000),
Empleado("pepe", "secretario", 33000),
Empleado("javier", "maestro", 25000),
Empleado("jorge", "contador", 64000)
]
salarios_altos=filter(lambda empleado:empleado.salario>50000, listaEmpleados)
for empleado_salario in salarios_altos:
    print(empleado_salario)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar está línea:

```
def ___init___(self, nombre, cargo, salario):
```

por esta otra

```
def __init__(self, nombre, cargo, salario):
```

Son sólo dos barras, no tres.

Comment: aaaaaahh, duré rato buscando el error y no me percate de eso, gracias!

Comment: Claro, según el tipo de letra que uses en el IDE no se nota cuantas barras escribiste.

Comment: que letra me recomiendas?

Comment: Uso un font monoespaciado en Pycharm. Busca uno que te muestre un pequeño espacio entre cada barra.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda!